# SQL Server Managed Instance database properties window getting “Subquery returned more than 1 value” error message

Tags: database, properties, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance

Error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

window prompt when opening database properties

[image]

Tried to run this script

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory 
          @database_name = N’<DBName>’
```

to delete the backup history - but the issue persists.